# Replicate order summary block Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-summary

I want to add an order summary on the checkout success page, I want to replicate the existing order summary block and template file whether it's from backend or frontend.

Which block and template file to use for order summary, including discount, tax, shipping, etc in detail?

Comment: are you referring to the side bar summary block during checkout steps?